# Não consigo fazer com que uma TextView exiba o conteúdo presente em um EditText!

Tags: android, edittext, textview

Criei um app onde em seu layout contém uma **EditText** e uma **TextView**.

O conteúdo inicial da TextView é: **"sem nome"**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o conteúdo da **TextView** fosse alterado quando eu inserisse algo no **EditText**, o que não ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu utilizei uma string para capturar o conteúdo do **EditText** para o **TextView** exibir o conteúdo dela, pois também precisarei exportar para uma próxima activity. Então não me serve algo direto como:

`TextView.setText(editText)`, mas sim `TextView.setText(String)`.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package genesysgeneration.ettotv;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etNome;
    private TextView tvNome;
    private String nome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etNome=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNome);
        tvNome=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNome);

        if (etNome.getText().length()==0){

            nome="SEM NOME";
            tvNome.setText(nome);

        }else {

            nome=etNome.getText().toString();
            tvNome.setText(nome);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso, é usar o método [**`addTextChangeListener()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)). Logo abaixo de suas condições, acrescente o código abaixo:

```
etNome.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

              tvNome.setText(s.toString());
              nome = s.toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Utilizando a classe [**`TextWatcher`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), você possui basicamente três métodos:

- `onTextChanged`: o que tem dentro dele é executado durante a alteração do texto.
- `afterTextChanged`: o que tem dentro dele é executado imediatamente após o texto ser alterado.
- `beforeTextChanged`: o que tem dentro dele é executado no instante antes em que o texto será alterado.

Para mais detalhes, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)).

Comment: Funfou, agora está apresentando o atraso de um caracter na TextView. Tipo... digito o nome "Cavalo" no EditText, na TextView aparece "Caval". Apagando um caracter ou adicionando aí sim aparece "Cavalo", porém os conteúdos da EditText e TextView nunca estão ficando iguais.

Comment: Coloquei no onTextChanged e ficou tudo sussa!!!

Comment: O valor da String não está mudando!!!

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso você viu a explicação sobre o onTextChanged né?! Beleza, se funcionar pra você direitinho, é só validar a resposta. Boa sorte!

Comment: o valor da string não está mudando!!!

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso coloque o `nome = s.toString();` também dentro do `onTextChanged` que vai alterar.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso desta forma, sua string recebe também o valor que está dentro do `EditText`